# Observe LiveData from foreground service

Tags: android, android-service, android-livedata

I have a repository which holds the LiveData object and is used by both
activity and a foreground service through a ViewModel.
When I start observing from the activity everything works as expected.
However observing from the service doesn't trigger the Observe.
This is the code I use

```
class MyService: LifecycleService() {
     lateinit var viewModel: PlayerServiceViewModel

     override fun onCreate() {
          viewModel = MyViewModel(applicationContext as Application)
     }

     override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
          viewModel.getLiveData().observe(this, Observer { data ->
            // Do something with the data
        })
     }
}
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work and I don't receive the data?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I used `ViewModel` with `LiveData` in `LifecycleActivity` and `Fragments` it works and observes data as expected.

Coming to your problem, when you create **new** `ViewModel` from `Service` or any another `Activity` it creates **new instance** of all the LiveData and other dependencies required for `ViewModel` to query from Repository and ultimately DAO.
If you are not using the same DAO for both ViewModels your `LiveData` may not update *as it is observing on **different** instance of DAO*.

I used `Dagger2` in my project to maintain Singleton instances for DAO and other common dependencies. So you can try making your Repository and DAO **singleton** to keep it consistent across the Application.

I tried it using with `Services` with `LifecycleService` with same flow and it worked for me.

I got following output when data changed form null to pulled data

```
D/ForegroundService: onStartCommand: Resource{status=LOADING, message='null', data=null}
D/ForegroundService: onStartCommand: Resource{status=SUCCESS, message='null', data=TVShow(id=14,...
```

At first it showed null data as data wasn't present in database
After pulling data from network and updating into database `Observer` observed data automatically.

Worked out using following code

```
public class ForegroundService extends LifecycleService {

    private static final String TAG = "ForegroundService";

    private TVShowViewModel tvShowViewModel;
    private TVShow tvShow;

    @Inject TVShowDataRepo tvShowDataRepo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        tvShowViewModel = new TVShowViewModel(tvShowDataRepo);
        tvShowViewModel.init(14);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        tvShowViewModel.getTVShow().observe(this, tvShowResource -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: " + tvShowResource);
        });
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.
I was using Singletons the whole time, but the issue turned out to be missing the `super.onCreate()` and `super.onStartCommand()`.
I figured that out after updating the AS and the kotlin plugin, which started complaining about the missing calls.

Comment: Using ViewModels in Services is not recommended. See [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/137)

Comment: @hara yes. They don't recommend to use it with service because `Service` is not holding any View and doesn't make any sense to use `ViewModel` as its Lifecycle aware with Views like Activity and Fragments
But we can use different class to hold our `LiveData` instead of `ViewModel` because `context` for those `LiveData`  `observers` is service anyway. 
So will be able to access `LiveData` without defining it inside `ViewModel`

Comment: @adityakamble49 I am getting this exception when extending my Service with `LifecycleService` 

> java.lang.InstantiationException: ... has no zero argument constructor
 
If I google, usually this error shows up with IntentService but this is not an IntentService. I have the right injection. Any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: Instead of using viewmodel in service, can we not have singleton dao instance in service and update the dao in service which will automatically update the data in viewmodel used by activity and thus the UI?

Comment: @Samyak, +. Viewmodel exists for UI, not service. In service we must access memory without view model, for example with repository