# Observe LiveData from JobService

Tags: android, android-service, android-architecture-components, android-jobscheduler, android-livedata

I have a repository which holds the `LiveData` object and is used by both `Activity` and now it's needed in `JobService` (From Firebase dispatcher) through a `ViewModel`.

There is answer for plain `Service` over here: [Observe LiveData from foreground service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708202/observe-livedata-from-foreground-service)

But it doesn't mention how to do the same for `JobService`.

Comment: Try to play with creating custom lifecycle component https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html#implementing-lco . To start working LifecycleRegistry properly, you should call https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistry.html#handleLifecycleEvent(android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle.Event) method in proper order.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to observe a LiveData object from something that isn't a LifecycleOwner, you can use the `observeForever` method.

```
val data = getLiveDataFromSomewhere()
data.observeForever(object: Observer<Whatever> {
    override fun onChanged(stuff: Whatever?) {
        // do something with stuff
        data.removeObserver(this)
    }
})
```

Comment: I got an exception that stated `Cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread` and used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58131708/4232765) answer as a solution.