# Camerax run in service . How to get lifecycleowner or run without it inside a foreground service?

Tags: android, android-camera2, background-service, android-camerax

**Use case** : is that  I have to run camera in background inside a service without any activity or fragment

**Blocker** : New camerax session is bind to lifecycleowner but the service don't have any .So how to get this object or run without it ?

**Already tried** : The same thing I am able to do with Camera2 library but I want to know whether it is possible with Camerax also because Camera2 api might get deprecated in future .
Or google is intentionally trying to block user from running camera without activity?

Please suggest

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/androids-camerax-jetpack-library-is-now-in-beta-bf4cf0cc3ea6 beta release

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried extending [LifecycleService](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleService) instead of regular `Service`? For that you'll need to add `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.x.y` as a dependency in your gradle file if you haven't already. Then, when you call `bindToLifecycle` method you just pass `this` as a parameter and it should work:

```
class ExampleService : LifecycleService() {
    // here should be use case implementation
    ...
    processCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, ...)
```

(disclaimer: didn't test this so I'm not 100% sure).

Also, starting with Android 11 you should include [following snippet](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#types) for this to work:

```
<manifest>
...
<service ... android:foregroundServiceType="camera" />
```

More on `LifecycleService` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708202/observe-livedata-from-foreground-service).

Comment: Service has different lifecycle than activity fragment . I thought of this idea but was unable to implement since CameraX uses activity lifecycleobserver. 
Please let me know if it works for you .

Comment: I was targeting android 6 to 9

Comment: Also read developer answer about camera implementation in background:
https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/S-SVqEY1-Cg

Answer (score 1):

LifecycleService doesn't work for me but custom ServiceLifeCycleOwner makes job great:

```
class ServiceLifeCycleOwner : LifecycleOwner {

   private val lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)

   init {
       lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.CREATED
   }

   fun start() {
       lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.STARTED
   }

   fun stop() {
       lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED
   }

   override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle = lifecycleRegistry
}
```

Then you can capture image like this:

```
    fun captureImage(cameraSelector: CameraSelector) {
    ...
       cameraProvider.unbindAll()
       cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifeCycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageCapture)
       lifeCycleOwner.start()
    ...
    }
```

See [google example](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt) how to use cameraX and thank you google for such simple and powerful api!